# How use Memory Sanitizer with use GCC?

Tags: gcc, clang, sanitizer

I want to use this kind of sanitizer in gcc. How can I do this? Is such an operation possible?

I found solution for clang:
`clang -fsanitize=memory -fno-omit-frame-pointer -g -O2 umr.cc` but I don't know how use this in gcc

Answer (score 5):

This is impossible - GCC does not support MSan.